# Why is it different with usage of 'data' in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I see the doc ( https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html )

the data is written as following .

```
data: {
    message: 'Hello'
},
```

But as I learned it should be like as followings

```
data: function () {
    return {
        message: '',
    }
},
```

Why is the vuejs so hard to understand code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must vue component data be a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826709/why-must-vue-component-data-be-a-function)

Comment: Thanks guys.. and sorry for inconvenience.